# Make logo scale down with browser

Tags: html, css

my logo is front & centre of my homepage (logo6.png below)
i need help to get it to scale down with broser size (make it responsive)
site is here: http://www.cobhseafoodco.com/torreen/
please help!

```
     <div class="container">
            <div class="content">   
                <img src="assets/img/logo6.png"/>
                <div class="separator-container">
                  <div class="separator line-separator">✻</div>
                </div>
                <h5>at Spiddal, Galway, Ireland</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what css have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

According to your site, i did some testing. Please paste this code in your css.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
    .content img {width:100%;}

}
```

i have checked your site and found under 510px resolution  your logo is not responsive but by this code your logo will be in center and responsive..let me know if you are facing any issue..ty

Comment: ty m glad i could help you..please accept my answer as answer..ty